# How to modify ArrayList declared in another activity?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, arraylist

I have an `ArrayList` let's call it list in `Activity A`. Now `Activity A` calls `Activity B` and `Activity B` calls `Activity C`. In `Activity C` I want to insert some elements in list and reflect those changes when i come back to `Activity A`.

Approaches i have taken

1) Declared `List` as public static so i can access it in any activity but the problem is list gets reinitialized when `Activity A` is called by `Activity C`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you initialise list in Activity A?

Comment: Where did you initialize the List?

Comment: Maintain the list in application class.

Comment: I am initialising the list in Activity A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not seem to be a good practice.

You can try doing like this:

1. Create another class, a `ListContainer`, with your static `mList` inside.
2. Access your list from any Activity using `ListContainer.getList()`
3. Inside getList() you must do `return mList==null ? new ArrayList() : mList`

I think it is a good way to do whatever you want to your list :D

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new class and put the ArrayList in it instead of Activity A. So, when Activity A is created, ArrayList won't be reinitialized.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on Observer pattern, it may help you. 
You can subscribe on changes in activity A and push them from any part of app if you are subscribed. 
Also here are some useful libs: EventBus, Otto.

Answer (score 0):

If your flow is from A -> B -> C and after making changes going from C->B->A then startActivityForResult and setting that result within and passing it along would be best approach to use..

Still if you want to go with static approach, then it should be initialized in Activity A only.. and there is no way that static arraylist initialized more then once.. it will always take single memory allocation and initialized for once only..

Answer (score 0):

When you need some variable accessible to different activities then you can declare, define and modify those kind of variable in Application class. You should declare those variables static and add getter & setter for these. Refer this for creating Application class:

https://guides.codepath.com/android/Understanding-the-Android-Application-Class

I am sure this will help you because we have solved this problem by this way.

Answer (score 0):

use singleton model class make array list there use this array-list anywhere and change from any class .just call classname .arraylist;

> otto is one more liabrary u can use you will get but i recomdent to make singleton model class

Answer (score 0):

You can define your list `static`. `static` variables are not often used due to some issues but you can use it for few (one or two) variables but use carefully. `static` variables can be used with class name like `ShoppingActivity.product_purchases`.